# Getting Sharp Architecture template to work with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, sharp-architecture

I've download  SharpArchApplicationTemplate_1_6_VS2010.zip

I have read through this:
http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/VSTemplatesAndCodeGen.ashx

However, this is aimed at VS 2008
I'm using 2010, and I can't see how to install the template(s)?

Have I downloaded the wrong thing?
I can't see anything on the wiki relating to 1.6 installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know 2008 templates will work just fine in 2010.  I briefly reviewed the install steps and they appear to be correct.  Here are the items you will need to change to install for Visual Studio 2010.

- Use the directory "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" instead of "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0"
- Use the directory "Visual Studio 2010" instead of "Visual Studio 2008"
- You will definitely have to run `devenv /installvstemplates`